# How to enter the word "NULL" into empty HTML table fields when data is being viewed in the browser?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a database in SQL which I have connected to successfully and I am displaying it on my web page. There are a lot of null fields in the database, so when I display the information in a table in the browser you see a lot of empty fields. I have tried using the empty-cell function but this doesn't seem to work. So I'd like to just have the word "NULL" in the empty fields.

I have asked this question already but it got closed as my question was a bit to vague. Please see my table code below:

```
<div id="displayBox" style="border: 3px solid #9C9595; height: 750; width: 1000px" class="blackBox">
<h2> View Sim Details </h2>
<table class="myTable" border="5">
<tr>
<th id="">ID</th>
<th id="">Number</th>
<th id="">Sim Card</th>
<th id="">ACCOLC</th>
<th id="">Notes</th>
<th id="">Next Upgrade</th>
<th id="">Pin</th>
<th id="">Puk</th>
<th id="">End Date</th>
<th id="">Update</th>
</tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With ASP classic, you could simply do something like this:

```
<td><%=StringIfNull(rs("SomeValue"))%></td>

function StringIfNull(value)
    StringIfNull = value

    if isnull(StringIfNull) then
        StringIfNull = "Null"
    end if
end function
```

Or you could handle this at the DB level:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SomeValue, 'Null') AS SomeValue FROM MyTable
```